# upgrade failed oracle apex 4.0 to 4.2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

i got stuck in a failed upgrade from apex 4.0 to 4.2

The following is the log after the upgrade. I only see application login page no other page including apex admin is working i-e. admin page loads but its blank.

1> my 11g XE installation is in G:\ORAXE.

2> i downloaded the application upgrade in downloads folder, and moved the extracted contents of apex folder to C:.

3> i am on hp desktop using windows 7 64bit.

```
C:\apex>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Mon Sep 29 10:01:00 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL>@apexins SYSAUX SYSAUX TEMP /i/
...
...
...
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> @apxldimg.sql C:\apex

...

declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
The system cannot find the path specified.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 296
ORA-06512: at line 16



PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


Commit complete.


Directory dropped.

timing for: Load Images
Elapsed: 00:00:10.98
SQL>
```

Comment: you are loading your image in apex then it gives error, SO please load them AT SQL> @apxldimg.sql C:\

Answer (score 1):

you are loading images at wrong location,load image at as follows

```
SQL> @apxldimg.sql C:\
```

for more
refer installation guide http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/upgrade-apex-for-xe-154969.html

Answer (score 0):

1. unzip your apex zip on a folder, for example: c:\apex
2. go to c:\apex
3. sqlplus  sys as sysdba
4. run previous scripts...
5. SQL> @apxldimg.sql C:\

**Notice that if you use c:\apex, the script will try to create a folder named images on c:\apex/apex/ , which is an inexistent directory**

Answer (score 0):

After having the same issue installing apex in dev enviroment for the third time, and reading, and searching, and guessing, [this link](http://yetanotheroracledbablog.blogspot.com/2015/08/running-2-versions-of-apex-in-same.html) confirmed what I was beginning to suppose.

When you download APEX from Oracle page, you get a zip file. This error is the result hardcoding paths in scripts, so when you unzip your downloaded file you have to unzip it to a folder named "apex" otherwise EPG configuration and images configuration will fail. If you want to keep track of the version of the unzipped apex version, you can have something like `c:\oracle\apex_18.2\apex`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem ... I tried everything I found that was supposed to resolved the problem ...

**Noted that this apply to windows installation and NOT Linux one.**

The fact is that someone mess it up when he made the script ... or maybe its a unix script that has been put in the windows installation kit by mistake, I don't know but the problem is :

Search in the files of your Apex upgrade folder where you unzip all the migration files for the upgrade and search all files for exactly "/apex/images".

You should find it in the file "apex_epg_config_core.sql".

Open this file and change (I found it only once in the file) "/apex/images" for "\apex\images" (change the slashs for back-slashs).  Noticed that mean that when you will enter the command in SQL, you should not include the "apex" directory in the path parameter to the script because the code in the script should not have been written "/apex/images" but only "\images" ... You can also correct it in the script and remove the "\apex" from the path in the sql file.

As an instance, in my case, I unzipped all the files in the folder "C:\temp\apex" ... so the right command for me to get it successfull without removing the "\apex" part from the path in the sql file was exactly "@apex_epg_config.sql C:\temp" and not "@apex_epg_config.sql C:\temp\apex" ...

After this, i can now log properly on my apex environment at "http://localhost:8080/apex/apex_admin" as stated in the installation guide ...

Hope this will help you guys ... (sorry for my poor english guys, i usually speak french...)

Thank you!

Comment: Why downvote? Change oracle provided scripts is not a good practice but... it seems that when you unzip  APEX downloaded file, you have to unzip it in a folder called "apex", otherwise it will fail while installing images and epg (as observed in my third apex installation).